# ¿Cómo modificar el valor de un objeto que esta dentro de un array? - PHP

Tags: php

Tengo el siguiente array:

> [{"2.91":2},{"2.3":0},{"0.46":2}]

Deseo modificar el valor del último elemento, es decir el objeto con la clave "0.46" quiero que su valor se incremente mas 1. Para ello hice lo siguiente:

En base a un array previamente cargado denominado `$longitudes_efectivas` tengo almacenados los valores 2.91 - 2.3 - 0.46, primeramente obtengo el valor menor del array con el siguiente código:

```
$indice = strval(min($longitudes_efectivas));
```

Y esto me devuelve el valor: 0.46. Luego lo que hago con este valor($indice) es buscar en la lista cuanto es el valor de la clave 0.46 y esto me devuelve 2 lo cual es correcto y posteriormente le sumo + 1:

```
$nuevo_valor = end($resultados)[strval($indice)] + 1;
```

Según la documentación de PHP dice que para modificar un elemento de un array debo crear un array que lo sustituya:

```
<?php
    $base = array("naranja", "plátano", "manzana", "frambuesa");
    $reemplazos = array(0 => "piña", 4 => "cereza");
    $reemplazos2 = array(0 => "uva");

    $cesta = array_replace($base, $reemplazos, $reemplazos2);
    print_r($cesta);
?>
```

Y siguiendo esa lógica hice lo siguiente:

```
$nuevo_array = array($indice => $nuevo_valor); // Creo un nuevo array con el nuevo valor
$resultados = array_replace($resultados, $nuevo_array); // Con esto se debería hacer el reemplazo
```

Pero obtengo el siguiente resultado:

> {"0":{"2.91":2},"1":{"2.3":0},"2":{"0.46":2},"0.46":3}

Lo cual no es lo que esperaba, lo que espero es lo siguiente:

> [{"2.91":2},{"2.3":0},{"0.46":3}]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hola Brynner el error que veo es que el formato de array que me muestras `[{"2.91":2},{"2.3":0},{"0.46":2}]` es un array de objetos el cual esta indexado automaticamente y la forma del indice para acceder al valor seria `$arr[2]->{0.46}=3;`.

**Solucion**

este formato es muy parecido al de json por lo que podrias decodificarlo:

```
$arr=json_decode('[{"2.91":2},{"2.3":0},{"0.46":2}]',true);
```

esto te daria este formato de Array

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [2.91] => 2 ) [1] => Array ( [2.3] => 0 ) [2] => Array ( [0.46] => 3 ) )
```

y podrias acceder al valor con sus claves asi: `$arr[2][0.46]=3` o `array_replace($arr, array( 2 => array("0.46"=>3)))`

***o***

puedes hacer un flatten y reemplazas el inexado automatico por la clave de cada array:

```
$arr=array_merge(...array_values($arr))
```

y aqui ya puedes acceder al valor normalmente `$arr[0.46]=3` o `array_replace($arr, array("0.46"=>3))`

**Nota:**

este operador `...` se llama spread